# Intellij keyboard shortcut to confirm replace current instance of find

Tags: intellij-idea

As shown in the screenshot the Find/Replace in-screen dialog is active.  Being required to use the Mouse to click on the "Re*p*lace" button is a **lousy** way to do business - especially for such a frequently used operation as find/replace.

[image]

It used to be possible to use "Alt-p" when a true dialog box were being used: but it now conflicts with the Build main menu item.

I would be fine with a custom keymap: but there does not appear to be any:

[image]

Have I missed anything here - i.e. were there some other keymap I'm not finding that provides the "confirm replace" functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it invokes the Replace action. Or at least it does now, maybe it didn't when you asked the question

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you can change only certain shortcuts in IntelliJ. For example, you won't be able to edit the shortcuts for the main menu items because these are fixed menu items. For ex: Alt+F being the file Menu Item and not being editable